# Excel REST API / Microsoft Graph - processing time allowance

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am evaluating the Excel REST APIs and understand that the computations are done server-side, so that if I update a cell via the REST APIs, the formulas are automatically re-calculated, and I can make a GET call to obtain new results. If I have a complicated spreadsheet with many cells and formulas, or want to do a large number of scenarios, or have a lot of workbooks to update in a batch, is there a limit to how much compute time I have? I cannot find in the docs if there is a limit or fair usage policy.

Furthermore, if I wanted to add more processing power, to speed up the calculations or run batch calculations, could this be done with the REST APIs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RobChooses,

Your assumption about how things work is correct - you POST values (or even formulas) to some cells, then you GET the values of calculated cells, and all the calculations take place in the cloud.

Calculations generated by API requests are performed by the same service that hosts Excel online for interactive users. Thus API usage is subject to the same limitations as interactive usage. Those limitations are subject to change, which is probably why they are not advertised.

There is no API that allows you to add more computing power directly on the Excel online hosting service - resource usage limits are typically a function of the tenant's subscription level.

To find out whether a particular workbook is supported, simply upload the workbook to your OneDrive for Business, open it in a browser, and make the desired changes interactively. If it works interactively, it should work programmatically too.